# spring security core plugin 4.0.3 recording the failed attempts

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using `Grails 4.0.9` and `spring security core grails plugin 4.0.3`, I searched for a way to capture the user failed and success login attempts but I didn't reach anything, is there a way to make this?

Comment: Do you want to keep a count of those and persist them somewhere?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes, I'm planning to use `Google Guava` https://github.com/google/guava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register `ApplicationListener` which listens to `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent` to handle failed attempts and register the same in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`. Such as:

```
package com.objectcomputing.example

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent

@Slf4j
@CompileStatic
class LoginFailedAuthEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent> {

    @Override
    void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent event) {
        final Object username = event.authentication.principal
        log.warn("Failed login attempt for username {}", username)
    }
}
```

Read more information at https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/4.0.x/index.html#registeringEventListener

**Please note** that the above listener is very basic which only logs the information but you could write whatever you need to do.

Example Application: https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-spring-security-demo

Comment: I did as mentioned, and  I was able to capture the failed attempts